# Disable selectList after selection is made

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, selectlist

I have a `selectList` in my VF page which allows the user to select the record type. On change the appropriate fields are shown to the user by re-rendering the *PageFields*.

But as well as re-rendering the **Pagefields** `outputPanel` I'd like to disable the selectList control (or even replace it with an `outputField` or label.

```
<apex:outputPanel id="RecordTypeBlank" rendered="{!recordType == ''}" >
    <div Id="RecordTypeQuestion">
        <div style="font-weight: bold;">
            Please select the record type before continuing
        </div>
        <table border="" style="width:100%;" >
            <tr>    
               <td valign="middle" align="right" style="width:21%; padding-right: 3px;" >
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Type of Change:"/>                                
                </td>
                <td valign="middle" align="left" style="width:79%; padding-left: 4px;" >
                    <apex:selectList value="{!recordType}" size="1">
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="PageFields" status="vfStatus"/>
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!RecordTypes}"/>
                    </apex:selectList>                      
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>    
    </div>
</apex:outputPanel>            

<apex:outputpanel id="PageFields" >
```

I tried changing the `onchange` event of the selectList as below:

```
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="PageFields RecordTypeBlank" status="vfStatus"/>
```

but that hasn't worked.

So how could I either disable the selectList, or dynamically replace it with an outputField showing the selected *recordType* (which is stored in the variable `!recordType` in my controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try one thing. Check if `recordType` not null then then hide this field

```
<apex:outputText value="{!recordType}" rendered="{!recordType != null || recordType != ''}"/ > 

<apex:selectList value="{!recordType}" size="1" rendered="{!recordType == null || recordType == ''}"">
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="PageFields" status="vfStatus"/>
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!RecordTypes}"/>
                    </apex:selectList>
```

use this sample code. It will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't replace the selectList with the `outputText`, possibly because the *RecordTypeBlank* block is not re-rendered

Comment: yes try to rerender that

Comment: if I try to add it as `<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="PageFields RecordTypeBlank"` none of the data entry fields are rendered on the change event

Comment: `<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="PageFields ,RecordTypeBlank"` and rerender the parent component of RecordTypeBlank field